# Store a UTC date with PHP to MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, utc

I have a mobile app and rest service. The mobile app will generate and provide the web service a UTC date time and time zone. I need to store both values into mysql using php.

I am acquiring the date time from a remote source, so I cannot use mysql's UTC_TIMESTAMP() to generate the 'current' utc time.

I have a table with 2 columns, created (DATETIME) and timezone (VARCHAR)

In PHP, I will collect the following:

```
$created = "2010-09-30 12:31:10"; //Actual UTC time
$timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
```

How would the INSERT statement be so it stores $created, as is (UTC), without it storing it as my server's default timezone?

Would I have to convert it from UTC to my server's local time in PHP or can it be side stepped some how in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, MySQL doesn't support time zone information on date columns, like for instance, PostgreSQL do.

Why can't you just store the date as is? I'm fairly sure that no conversion will take place. And also, why do you need the timezone info anyway? Isn't it more relevant to convert it to local time upon display, later on? For the specific user that is viewing the information?

"The current time zone setting does not affect values displayed by functions such as UTC_TIMESTAMP() or values in DATE, TIME, or DATETIME columns. Nor are values in those data types stored in UTC; the time zone applies for them only when converting from TIMESTAMP values. If you want locale-specific arithmetic for DATE, TIME, or DATETIME values, convert them to UTC, perform the arithmetic, and then convert back. " source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Meaning, MySQL only utilize the time zone information in order to return local time from TIMESTAMP() and similar functions, not for on the fly conversion of data inserted or selected.

Comment: I am displaying local time of where the time was captured, not the time or local time of the viewing client, ie browser. -wow that sounded funny :P

Comment: ok, so timestamps and mysql use its set timezone to do conversions, but datetime is just a date and time with no conversion when save or selected? ah, just saw your update...

Comment: Yeah, missed that part, DATETIME is unaffected, TIMESTAMP is not. I would say that storing it as UTC in a DATETIME with a separate time-zone would be the wya to go, or the timezone time if you ever only want to display it as the local timezone. You must also consider eventual DST when converting from UTC, hence storing local time might be easier in that regard.